# How to get the filepath from QFileSystemModel?

Tags: qt

First, suppose there is a folder storing several images. Then I try to click a button in the UI to open a folder and then save all the filepath of images in that folder into the QList (Only filtered image files). But the QList doesn't store anything. Please help.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"),
                                                 "/home",
                                                 QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly
                                                 | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    model = new QFileSystemModel();
    filesPath = dir;
    model->setRootPath(dir);
    QStringList filter;
    filter <<"*.png" <<"*.jpg" <<"*.bmp" <<"*.gif";
    model->setNameFilters(filter);
    model->setNameFilterDisables(false);

    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(dir));
    ui->treeView->setAnimated(false);
    ui->treeView->setSortingEnabled(true);   

    QList<QString> path_list;
    QModelIndex parentIndex = model->index(dir);
    int numRows = model->rowCount(parentIndex);

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
        QModelIndex childIndex = model->index(row, 0, parentIndex);
        QString path = model->data(childIndex).toString();
        if(!QFileInfo(path).isDir())
            path_list.append(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#details

Comment: @md612 Why you are using `QFileSystemModel` for that?

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov To use it with QtreeView

Comment: @md612. You didn't understand my question: Why you are using `QFileSystemModel` to populate list of files? It is not designed for that. But it is OK to use it in `QTreeView`.

Comment: I learn this model using with QTreeView from some examples.

Comment: Ok. Sure you may learn. But then your question is incorrect. Because your code works as expected.

Comment: "But the following code doesn't work. Please help." - Insufficient problem description. Please read: [ask]

Comment: I corrected my error message.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you intend, and with much less code and overhead, if you use [`QDir::entryList()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) with appropriate filters instead.

Comment: This is a useful answer for sure, it's just that the OP indicated he needed an item model to populate a tree view.  And the question was why does `QFileSystemModel` not work for populating the list. Oh well...  :P

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, `QFileSystemModel` wasn't designed to be used like that.  The key here is in the docs you were pointed to (emphasis mine):

> Unlike QDirModel, QFileSystemModel uses a separate thread to populate itself so it will not cause the main thread to hang as the file system is being queried. **Calls to rowCount() will return 0 until the model populates a directory.**

If you absolutely wanted to use `QFileSystemModel` to build a list, you'd have to connect a function to the `directoryLoaded(const QString &path)` signal and add the files in each folder once it was loaded... but there are probably much better ways to accomplish what you need.